# Extracting a range of data from a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of unicode values.  To the best of my knowledge I can use list[starting location:length to select] to select a range of values from a list, right?

I have a list of 78 unicode values, which are not all unique.  When I select a range of 5 values beginning from the 0 position in the list (example: list[0:5]) the correct values are returned.  However, when I try to select a range of values that do not begin at the 0 position in the list (example: list[44:5]) then the return is [].  Changing the length of the range does not seem to make any difference.  Furthermore, if I use list[44], for example, then the value that is returned is correct.

I do not understand why I cannot select from a list when the cursor is not located at 0.  Can anyone tell me if lists in python have limitations on how data can be retrieved as a range?  I hope my problem and question are clear enough.  I would appreciate any feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) on how slicing works may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up my misunderstanding about how the slice notation functioned.  Your comments were all very useful and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to the site and still getting my bearings, but I've checked the answer that was most informative (even though they were all helpful).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should do `list[44:49]` rather than `list[44:5]`.
Usually when you want to fetch 5 items after (including) the a+1th item, you do `L[a, a+5]`.
'Usually' implies there are more flexible ways to do so: see Extended Slices: http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html.

Also try not to use `list` as your list name. It overwrites `list()`.

Answer (score 9):

It is list[starting:ending] **not** list[starting:length].

So you should do `list[44:49]`

For more information on [slice notation click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3):

In the slice notation `[a:b]`, the second value (`b`) is not length, but a upper bound.

To get five elements starting from `44` you should use `[44:49]` (49 = 44 + 5)

If upper bound is smaller than lower bound, you get empty sequence.